# Отправка файла через curl без сохранения его на диске

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

Мой сайт скачивает и выгружает достаточно большое количество файлов круглосуточно. В среднем это до 10 миллионов файлов в сутки. Недавно столкнулся с ситуацией - ssd диски просто "умерли". Хотелось бы в связи с этим пересмотреть вопрос выгрузки файлов.
Сейчас все сделано так:

1. Скачиваем файл во временную папку
2. Выгружаем его с помощью curl
3. Удаляем временный файл.
   Хотелось бы сделать то же самое, но не сохраняя временный файл.
   Например, отправить на выгрузку

   $data = file_get_contents ( 'https://site.ru/path/to/file.pdf' );

Потратил целый день на поиски решения. Но почему то ни одна из предложенных реализаций у меня не сработала. Возможно, кто то реализовал похожее решение и сможет помочь?

Comment: тогда оперативки не хватит) хотя можно очередь прикрутить, но явно днем чел может очереди не дождаться

Comment: Оперативки хватит) Файлы в среднем по 150 килобайт, память при загрузке они все равно занимают)

Comment: а выгружаешь куда, каким образом, кому? на другой серв или пользователь на сайте скачивает файл через твой сайт-прокладку?

Comment: выгружается на другой серв)

Comment: вот ответ 2 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21905942/posting-raw-image-data-as-multipart-form-data-in-curl

Comment: Вполне можно это сделать помещая файлы в оперативную память, как уже упомянули здесь. Для этого можно использовать /dev/shm, либо memcached, либо ramdisk.